# HTML Form onSubmit not calling the javascript script

Tags: javascript, html, http-headers, redirect

I have a form as follows:

```
<form id='_authForm' action='targetURL' method='POST' onsubmit='return setCookie();'>
</form>
<script>
      function setCookie()
      {
        document.cookie="cookiefortest=test"; path="/";return false;
      }
      document.forms['_authForm'].submit();
</script>
```

And I am experiencing an issue when it is submitted, the javascript "setCookie();" method is not being called. **Does anyone knows how can I do this?**

Unfortunately I cannot have the setCookie javascript function already in the targetURL.

Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: calling submit() on the form will not fire the onsubmit event

Answer (score 1):

1. You have unescaped `"` characters in a string literal delimited by `"` characters. If `setCookie` was to run, it would throw an exception there. The cookie syntax does not use quote characters.
2. When a form is submitted using the `submit` method, a submit *event* is not fired. Run the function manually instead.

such:

```
  function setCookie()
  {
    document.cookie="cookiefortest=test; path=/";
    return false;
  }
  setCookie();
  document.forms['_authForm'].submit();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but for some reason it doesn't allow you to run the "setCookie()" function before the authForm submit. I tested in Safari, for instance. Don't understand why.

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't allow"? What happens when you try? If `setCookie()` fails, the code will never reach `submit()`.

Comment: I mean it doesn't run, and yes I changed the return to true.

Comment: So what happens? `setCookie();` doesn't run but `document.forms['_authForm'].submit();` does? And there are no errors on the console? That isn't possible. (The return value of `setCookie()` is irrelevant, it isn't used for anything).

Comment: No, it doesn't call the `setCookie();` neither the form submit. And the Safari, Snippet Editor doesn't show an error...